# Delete vertical spaces or new lines in Visual Studio Text Editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

this might be a silly questions but is there a way to delete new lines in visual studio's text editor? 
for example if i have two methods with lots of spaces/newLines between them:

```
protected void BtnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Code
}




protected void DeleteItem()
{
   //Code
}
```

can visual studio format and trim new lines so they look something like this:

```
protected void BtnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Code
}   

protected void DeleteItem()
{
   //Code
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, VS can't do it without extensions. You can use tools like [CodeRush](http://devexpress.com/Products/CodeRush). I suppose [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can do it also.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an extension, such as [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/). It has this specific feature, plus tons of other code clean-up features.

Answer (score -1):

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, Visual Studio should format your document according to the settings under **Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting**.

Comment: yep that helps mostly in indentation but not in this case.

Comment: That doesn't format vertical whitespace like the question asked.